# JavaFX dialogs continuous progress bar

Tags: java, hibernate, javafx

Is possible to create a window dialog with JavaFX Dialogs that shows a "fake" progress bar (the one that is used when you don't have control of the percentage of the task, for example when a program crashes on windows 8 and the SO tries to find a solution for the error)?

I want to run the hibernate startup in a separated thread, and while it's loading I want show the progress bar dialog, but i'm not sure of how to do it with the information on the Dialogs official website.

Comment: Yes it is, have you tried anything which is not working? Take a look at [Task](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) documentation.

Comment: The code for opening the Hibernate in a separated thread is working, I'm just not sure if is possible to show a progress dialog while it's loading

Comment: Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22478862/1025201) answer for an overview. Or [this](http://www.asgteach.com/blog/?p=219) tutorial

Comment: I still don't know how to achieve what i want. The progress dialog that i refer to is exactly like this one: http://thewindowsclub.thewindowsclubco.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Windows-Explorer-Has-Stopped-Working.png?bbdc8f

Comment: Also there's no way to know the hibernate progress, so i can't update the progress bar inside the Task because i really don't know the progress

Comment: Just set the progress of your task to be negative (`updateProgress(-1,1);`), or set the progress of your progress bar directly to -1.